# Can I use a Zip Code for a WaypointParameterType?

Tags: rest, here-api

I'm using the [Here Calculate Route API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/resource-calculate-route.html)

The [waypoint](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/resource-param-type-waypoint.html) query parameters use geo lat/long in the format.

Example `waypoint0=geo!52.5,13.4`

I would like to use **Zip Codes** instead of lat/long values.

Is that possible with the Calculate Route API?

Comment: I don't see zip code mentioned on that page, so no?

Comment: @HereticMonkey that is why I was asking

Answer (score 1):

As Heretic Monkey says, it isn't documented (you can see the documentation for this at https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/resource-param-type-waypoint.html) so the answer is no. However, you could consider geocoding the zip code (https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/dev_guide/topics/quick-start-geocode.html) and using that result. It's going to be somewhat vague, but it may work for you.

Comment: As an FYI, I tested geocoding *just* a zipcode and you definitely can do that.

Comment: yea I have it working by geocoding first, but every call costs money.  I was just trying to reduce the amount of HTTP requests.  thank you for your comment

Comment: Don't forget once you geocode a zipcode you don't have to do it again if you persist the result. :)

Comment: was exactly my plan!